# YA book- young girl discovers talking mythical creature, maybe a griffin

Tags: story-identification, books, magic, young-adult

From what I remember, the protagonist is pretty young, maybe 13 or 14 years old. She discovers a mythical creature on a walk outside; I think it was a griffin, but I'm not entirely sure. It's tied to her discovering she has magic powers. She has to hide the creature from the rest of her non magical family. She has a little brother.

Pretty sure it would be set in the early 90s, I remember a description of the girl talking on a corded telephone. YA fantasy.

Comment: You have a decent description here but could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, what was this a novel, novella, short story, TV show, movie etc.?

Comment: Is magic a known element in the world or is it a more mundane world like our own?

Comment: Further question- is this a book? If so, was it in English?

Comment: Yes, it was a book, and written in English. I would say the world was just like our own, and magic was not a normal part of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the book! I can't believe it. It's called [*My Aunt, the Monster*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1415926.My_Aunt_the_Monster) by Mary Stanton. The front cover has a picture of the girl on a corded phone with her little brother next to her, and a griffin in the foreground. So at least the details I gave weren't too far off the mark. So relieved I can lay this to rest!

[image: My Aunt, the Monster front cover]